# Laravel Artisan error: Target class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Once our Laravel app is deployed to hosting (AWS Elastic Beanstalk) it's impossible to run `php artisan` from the ssh command prompt. Every time results in the following error:

> In Container.php line 879:
> **Target class [request] does not exist.**
>
> In Container.php line 877:
> **Class "request" does not exist**

Even just running `php artisan` without any parameters results in the same error. Locally everything is fine.

Strangely AWS runs certain bash `php artisan` commands as part of `postdeploy` hooks which work fine during deployment (eg. `artisan config:cache`). They work fine, but even if I disable that bash script and try to run those commands manually via ssh after deploy, I get the same error. Very confusing.

It's as if there's something happening after deployment that's breaking `php artisan`.

We're running `PHP 8.0.18` and `Laravel 9.0.1`. I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, but I still get the same error while that's running.

Where would be the right place to start looking for the cause of this error message?

Comment: you run artisan command in your laravel project root folder?

Comment: @MartinAmu Yes of course

Comment: I found this through search and i'm not sure this is a solution but look at the best answer please.

Comment: @MartinAmu Huh?

Comment: Try setting `APP_ENV` to `local`, tell me what happens.